# How to update AWS ECS cluster instances with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I have an existing ECS cluster (EC2) created using Terraform. I want to install some software on those EC2 instances using Terraform. One of our business requirements is that we will not be able to destroy and re-create the instances and we have to do it on existing instances.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your organization is experimenting with running its services in docker and ECS. I also assume you are using AWS ECR to host your docker images (although technically doesn't matter).

When you create an ECS cluster it is initially empty. If you were to re-run your terraform template again it should show you that there are no updates to apply. In order to take the next step you will need to define a **ecs-service** and a **ecs-task-definition**. This can either be done in your existing terraform template, in a brand new template, or you can do it manually (aws web console or awscli). Since you are already using terraform I would assume you would continue to use it. Personally I would keep everything in 1 template but again it is up to you.

An ecs-service is essentially the runtime configuration for your ecs-tasks
An ecs-task-definition is a set of docker containers to run. In the simplest case it is 1 single docker container. Here is where you will specify the docker image(s) you will use, how much CPU+RAM for the docker container, etc...

In order for your running ecs service(s) to be updated without your EC2 nodes ever going down you would just need to update your docker image within the ecs-task-definition portion of your terraform template (an ofcourse run terraform).

with all this background info now you can add a [Terraform ecs-service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html) [Terraform ecs-task-definition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html) to your terraform template.

Since you did not provide your template I cannot say exactly how this should be setup but an example terraform template of a complete ECS cluster running nginx can be found below
[Complete Terraform ECS example](https://github.com/anrim/terraform-aws-ecs)
more examples can be found at
[Official terraform ECS github examples](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs/tree/master/examples/complete-ecs)

Answer (score 0):

You could run a [`provisioner`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) attached to an always triggered [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) to always run some process against things but I'd strongly recommend you rethink your processes.

Your ECS cluster should be considered completely ephemeral, as with the containers running on them. When you want to update the ECS instances then destroying and replacing the instances (ideally in an autoscaling group) is what you want to do as it greatly simplifies things. You can read more about the [benefits](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/what-is-mutable-vs-immutable-infrastructure) of immutable infrastructure [elsewhere](https://blog.codeship.com/immutable-infrastructure/).

If you absolutely couldn't do this then you'd most likely be best off using another tool, such as Ansible, entirely. You could choose to launch this via Terraform using a `null_resource` provisioner as mentioned above which would look something like the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "on_demand_provisioning" {
  triggers {
    always = "${uuid()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml --ssh-common-args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'"
  }
}
```